# Unauthorized response when downloading file with Service Account in Google Drive API

Tags: c#, .net, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-drive-api

I'm using the following code to get `credentials` from Google's Authentication server in order to access the `Google drive API`

```
 public static Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer getCredentials()
    {

        String serviceAccountEmail = "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"xxx.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));



        return new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "AppName",
        };



    }
```

then retrieving the Download url from the file metadata and attempting to download that file with the following code:

```
 public static System.IO.Stream DownloadFile(Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file, Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService service)
   {



       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.DownloadUrl))
       {
           try
           {
               HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                   new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
              // authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);
               HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
               if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
               {
                   return response.GetResponseStream();
               }
               else
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(
                       "An error occurred: " + response.StatusDescription);
                   return null;
               }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
               return null;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
           return null;
       }
   }
```

However I'm receiving a `401 unauthorized` response. I'm assuming I need to add an Authorization header in the request along the lines of Authorization: `Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}` but the `HttpClientInitializer.Token` property is null. Is it possible to authenticate this Request using the `ServiceAccountCredential`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem today. Using your approach to make a request no Authentication header is provided. I needed to construct the request a bit differently. Where you have:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
               new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
```

You should have:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await service.HttpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
```

This ensures that the request is properly authenticated.

Comment: Perfect. I was able to use service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(new Uri(file.DownloadUrl)) to do exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is off a little.  I don't have a service account Google Drive API example right this minute.  This is one for Big Query its almost the same.

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "539621478854-imkdv94bgujcom228h3ea33kmkoefhil@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\linda_l\Documents\GitHub\GoogleBigQueryServiceAccount\GoogleBigQueryServiceAccount\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
       new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
          {
           Scopes = new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.DevstorageReadOnly }
          }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
var service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
       HttpClientInitializer = credential,
       ApplicationName = "BigQuery API Sample",
       });
```

Can you see where the `BaseClientService.Initializer()`  is used to create the `BigqueryService`.  I think you need to create a `GoogleDriveService`.   Once you have created the service you should be able to use the service to download the file.  You shouldn't need to be doing it though a HTTPRequest.

I will see if i can find a better example tonight using Google Drive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605526/c-sharp-google-drive-service-account-download-issue?noredirect=1#