# Google drive service account download issue

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I created service account, I exposed several files to this account and once I wanted to download files it throws following exception

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Bad Request [400]
>   Errors [
>       Message[Bad Request] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
>   ]

```
 var certificate = new X509Certificate2("*******.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        try
        {
            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("*******..com")
               {
                   Scopes = scopes
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.
            DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Daimto Drive API Sample",
            });
            var files = service.Files.List().Execute().Files;
            var request = service.Files.Get(files.First().Id);

            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(); 
            request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
                (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
                {
                    switch (progress.Status)
                    {
                        case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                                break;
                            }
                        case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                                break;
                            }
                        case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                };
            request.Download(stream);
```

Comment: Try checking the [Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation) for Google Drive v2 concerning your service account. Also check the admin console if you have properly assigned the service account for you apps.

Comment: I do not possess google for work account in case of delegation of authority. I can successfully download default file assigned to account "GET STARTED" but not files exposed from diffrent account, alas.

Comment: which method is throwing the error?

Comment: within ProgressChanged method Status is Failed and error equals 400 Bad request as mentioned above.

Comment: I exposed file to equivalent email I am using in Initializer's constructor. The file is listed in service.Files.List().Execute() and as I said, "Get Started" that is default file does not have status failed, others do.

Comment: Exact same error here

Comment: Since nobody gave any hint I gave up on using google drive and downloaded file directly from url instead. Url looks as follows: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={0}